# Validation rule to allow 1 field editing and rest locked if record is older than year

Tags: validation-rule, activity

If activity is older than 1 year then "Data Analyst" profile should be allowed to edit only WhoId field (moving contact) but not rest. Sys Admin has no restrictions. I have used below rule but fails if user changes other fields along  with WhoId, any help would be appreciated.

```
AND 
( 
 (Today()-DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)>365), 
 $Profile.Name <>"System Administrator", 
 NOT( AND($Profile.Name = "Data Analysts", ISCHANGED(WhoId)) 
     ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are checking for changes in all other fields, you'll need a trigger. It should describe the object, run through each field, and compare the values in Trigger.old and Trigger.new for each field in each record.

Pseudocode:

```
    Describe object and put fieldnames into fieldlist
    for(rec : Trigger.new){
        for(each : fieldlist){
           if( <profile logic, date logic> 
               && each != 'WhoId' 
               && Trigger.newMap.get(rec.Id) != Trigger.oldMap.get(rec.Id)){ 
                   throw error on that record; 
                   continue;
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidSchach for the comments. I was looking any configuration changes to meet this requirement but with your comments it seems not possible just with validation rule.

Answer (score 1):

I have enhanced @DavidSchach code and below is the final one along with validation rule:
   Set updateableFields = new Set();
    for (SObjectField field : SObjectType.Task.fields.getMap().values())
    {
        if (field.getDescribe().isUpdateable() && !String.valueOf(field).equalsIgnoreCase('WhoId'))
        {
            updateableFields.add(String.valueOf(field));
        }
    }

```
for (Task newTask: Trigger.new) {
    Task oldTask = Trigger.oldMap.get(newTask.ID);
    for(String fieldName : updateableFields){
        if(newTask.get(fieldName) != oldTask.get(fieldName)){
            newTask.put(fieldName, oldTask.get(fieldName));
        }
    }
}
```